# Change Button Color even after clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the color of the button once the button is clicked. I was looking at examples on here and I finally got the color to change once clicked, however when I click somewhere else (anywhere off the button) then that css class goes away. These buttons are inside of a form so I wanted them to have the active state css until the form is submitted.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
jQuery('.choose-school').click(function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
  if (jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
    jQuery(this).text('SELECTED');
  } else {
    jQuery(this).text('SELECT');
  }
});
```

```css
.choose-school.active {
  background-color: #eeffd4;
}
.choose-school:active {
  background-color: #eeffd4;
}
.choose-school:focus {
  background-color: #eeffd4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="choose-school">
  <h3>Testing
    <span class="select-active">SELECT</span>
</button>
```

I tried using thiings like :active and :focus to see if that would help, but it didn't. In the JQuery I'm also trying to change that span text change from "SELECT" to "SELECTED" anyone know what is wrong with that part of the code as well?

Comment: Your code is almost working to me. check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/m202zz0j/ I only changed the eventhandler to an "on" event

Comment: The code is working for me just fine [example](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/VeePjL)

Comment: for find for me too in chrome 47

Comment: You are missing a closing `<h3>` tag...

Comment: @Julo0sS perfect! Okay the problem is now it changes the whole button to say selected! I want it to just change the "Select" to "Selected" so basically just target that span or span class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$.html()` instead of `$.text()`. The text replacer will drop all tags and only keep the text.

The easy way is to get the HTML as a string, replace it, then set it. See the example below:

```js
jQuery('.choose-school').click(function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
  if (jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
    jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().replace('SELECT', 'SELECTED'));
  } else {
    jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html().replace('SELECTED', 'SELECT'));
  }
});
```

```css
.choose-school.active {
  background-color: #eeffd4;
}
.choose-school:active {
  background-color: #eeffd4;
}
.choose-school:focus {
  background-color: #eeffd4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="choose-school">
  <h3>Testing
    <span class="select-active">SELECT</span>
  </h3>
</button>
```

The best way is to replace the text inside the span:

```js
jQuery('.choose-school').click(function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
  if (jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
    jQuery(this).find('.select-active').html('SELECTED');
  } else {
    jQuery(this).find('.select-active').html('SELECT');
  }
});
```

```css
.choose-school.active {
  background-color: #eeffd4;
}
.choose-school:active {
  background-color: #eeffd4;
}
.choose-school:focus {
  background-color: #eeffd4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="choose-school">
  <h3>Testing
    <span class="select-active">SELECT</span>
  </h3>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few problems with your code:

#### Your html `<h3>` was not closed

```
<h3>Testing</h3>
```

#### You tried changing the text for the entire button and not only the text inside

This will modify the span inside:

```
$(this).find('.select-active').text('SELECTED');
```

#### (semantical) You can use `$` for instead of `jQuery`

```
$(this) // ...
```

Fiddle with fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/fyha5m9g/

Comment: Don't use $(this) everywhere. Save it once in a variable :)

Comment: Yeah I usually do that, just didn't wanna get too nitpicky on the answer here... hehe

Answer (score 0):

You should create new class in css file and apply it when you click the button. Don't use focus on button, it's not useful there. Do like this:

```
<script>
jQuery('.choose-school').click(function(){

        if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active')){
          jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
          jQuery(this).text('SELECTED');
        }else{
          jQuery(this).addClass('active');
          jQuery(this).text('SELECT');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Css file

```
.choose-school.active {
    background-color: #eeffd4; 
}
```